# How to redirect to a view from another view in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a table which contains some datas. I want to do that I click edit button in the row and redirect to `UserCustomerCommunication` view with that record's Id. But when I click it try to send me to somewhere in the same view. How should I set the url routing? Do you have any suggestions?
Here is my Edit button redirect code in Index of GetCustomerCommunicationResult view :

```
     @Html.ActionLink("Düzenle", "Edit", new { id = item.CommunicationId }) |
```

[image]

Comment: You don't redirect to views. You redirect to controller actions. What controller action are you trying to redirect to?

Comment: I want to redirect to Edit action in CustomerCommunicationController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redirect from views to views, but you can to action methods(even from another controller). Use this overload of ActionLink to specify exactly where you want to redirect.

`@Html.ActionLink("Düzenle", "Edit", "ControllerName", new { id = item.CommunicationId}, null)`

That last parameter is the html attrributes, since you are not passing anything, set it to null.